# What does x++ in JavaScript do?

Tags: javascript

I have a very short question, but it really confused me.

```
var y = 3, x = y++;
```

What is the value of x?

I thought the answer should be 4, but actually it's 3.

Can anyone explain me the reason?

Comment: x = y++ here the value is assigned and then incremented. this x=++y will increment and assign.

Comment: when you do x = y++ ; first it will assign the value of y to x and then it increments.

Answer (score 10):

`y++` is called *post-increment* -- it increments the variable *after* it returns the original value as the value of the expression. So

```
x = y++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
temp = y;
y = y + 1;
x = temp;
```

If you want to return the new value, you should use `++y`. This is called *pre-increment* because it increments the variable *before* returning it. The statement

```
x = ++y;
```

is equivalent to:

```
y = y + 1;
x = y;
```

Comment: Official docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment

Answer (score 0):

In `y++`, `++` is called "post-increment operator". It first uses the value of `y`, then increments `y`. In this, is contrasts to a "pre-increment operator", `++y`, which first increments `y`, then returns the incremented value.

Answer (score 0):

The `++` operator does two things. It increments a variable and it returns the value of the variable.

If you prefix it, ie `++y`, it will return the value after the increment (in your case, 4). If you postfix (`y++`)it, it will return the value before the increment (in your case 3. Note that the value of `y` is now still 4, but x was assigned before y was incremented).

Answer (score 0):

```
var y = 3;
x = ++y;
console.log(x);
```

This will result in `4`

This is called "pre-increment". Where it returns the incremented value .

`y++` is post-increment, which returns the original value.